# CSS Background RGBA & BG Image

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my CSS. I want to make the left section of my website a scrolling background.

As you can see below, the RGBA is overlapping the whole page, but I want it to only overlap the background image. Same goes for the gridtile (the overlay image).

Is this possible to do?

I'm thinking of making this effect with HTML if this isn't possible to do with CSS. I would like some on what's better: CSS or HTML. Because I want to keep it mobile friendly, of course.

```css
body {
 background:linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) ),url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP9FG.png") fixed,url("http://placehold.it/180x50") fixed repeat-y;
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of what is happening now and what your desired effect is?

Comment: @Adjit The snippet is the problem actually, the overlay RGBA and image needs to be overlaying the background image but overlays the whole page. I will post a pic to explain it more.

Comment: Oh, well that is obvious because you are setting it to the `body` - if you want to have separate backgrounds you will need to set it do some `div`s

Comment: @Adjit Is there are other way without DIVs? I can't add HTML to my page because I'm using WordPress child themes. I'm currently trying stuff with Pseudo Elements.

Comment: can't you set background-size to the size of the image?

Comment: Honestly don't know. I am unfamiliar with wordpress. But I don't have any idea on how you can achieve this without that. Because you have multiple background images, so setting a `background-size` will affect both pictures

Comment: @Adjit Best option is to photoshop the overlay and overlay image to the background image.

Comment: @Adjit Just wanted to let you know; I've created a hook inside my functions.php so I can add HTML to the page; so for anyone who has the same problem, create a custom hook. :) Thanks for your advice, sir.

Comment: Good for you! Glad you figured it out. You can post an answer with your solution for others that come across this

Answer (score 0):

For the CSS, I have created a DIV and added the same exact CSS used in the answers' snippet to that DIV.

---

For the HTML in a WordPress child theme, I have created this solution:

Add this to your **functions.php**:

```
function before_end_func() {
    echo '<div class="sidebg"></div>';
}
add_action('before_end', 'before_end_func');
```

Then, add this to your **footer.php** of your framework/primary theme before `</body>`:

```
do_action('before_end');
```

Note that you do have to add it everytime the developers update their framework/theme.